# Run AZCopy via Powershell and Monitor Progress

Tags: powershell, azcopy

Is it possible to run AZCopy.exe via powershell and be able to view or output the real-time copy progress somewhere visible? When running it through a standard command line it will display the copy progress and speed in the console window, but when running it in powershell this doesn't display. Otherwise the utility runs fine and returns the final output upon completion. If this isn't possible, do you have any other tips on how to automate azcopy via powershell and interact with the output or results programatically. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you run AzCopy in a PowerShell ISE window?

If you run it in PowerShell Window, it will have progress. (I test with AzCopy 6.1 on PowerShell 5.1)

If you run AzCopy in PowerShell ISE, it will not have progress. But can show the transfer summary when transfer finished.